# Failure to install QGIS 2 - held broken packages

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu, qgis-2

I pasted the issue about not being able to install QGIS 2 on Ubuntu Raring on an ubuntu forum: launchpad.net apt questions and the answer seemed to indicate the problem is with QGIS?  Thread: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+question/236907

A copy of the thread is attached via the preceding link hoping there's someone who knows what is going on with this program.  Unfortunately I can't use Linux or a version of it at the moment as I can't get QGIS to work on it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix ubuntugis-unstable and qgis.org repositories. You have to chose only one otherwise you mess up your system. Remove everything. Disable one of the repos and reinstall.

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu raring main

deb http://qgis.org/debian raring main
```